# Run Command before automatic backup

Tags: 11.10, backup, deja-dup

I've been using the Deja Dupe to run automatic backups on my system.  The problem I'm having is my server at work occasionally times out and essentially un-mounts my windows shares from Nautilus.  I'd like to find a way to run `nautilus smb://windowsmountpoint` before it Deja Dupe runs the automatic backup.  I can't imagine this feature not existing, I just don't know how to do it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There probably *is* a way but it's probably not that pretty. I'd probably suggest making the connection to the server more reliable.

I'd suggest something like an `/etc/fstab`-`cifs` mount [like this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently):

```
//servername/sharename  /media/mountname  cifs  guest,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,codepage=unicode,unicode  0  0
```

You can tailor that to use credentials if you need.

If that's still dropping off, you can [use `autofs`](http://www.howtoforge.com/accessing_windows_or_samba_shares_using_autofs) which is great for dynamically mounting things.

Comment: That way makes a lot more sense, however I get mount error(115) after running sudo mount -a with that in fstab.  Any ideas?